# U-substitution step to solve Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

I'm looking at how an integral was computed in "Paul's online math notes" in the section on U-substitution and am a bit confused.  In the original expression there are $2$ $x$'s, one in front of $\cos$ and the other as the numerator in the second term.  When he substitutes $xdx=\dfrac{1}{2}du$ why does $\dfrac{1}{2}du$ replace both $x$ terms?

thanks

---

[image]

Comment: The formulas are written loosely, there are missing (or implied) parenthesis.

Comment: ok.  So the $dx$ or $du$ at the end of an integral is always assumed to be outside parentheses that contain the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are factoring the $x$ out of both terms so there will only be one $x$ in front of parenthesis.

It is just a matter of convenience. You do not have to factor if you do not like it. Then of course you have  two $ xdx$ to deal with.

Comment: Yes, that is what they meant. The parenthesis  around \cos(u) +1/u was left out.